# Select unique combinations in a list

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to generate unique combinations of numbers that sum up to specific target:

```
 class Solution:
  def combinationSum(self, candidates, target):

    chosen = []
    res = []
    self.combinationHelper(candidates, chosen, target, res)

    return res

def combinationHelper(self, nums, chosen, target, res):
    if sum(chosen) > target:
        return
    if sum(chosen) == target:
        res.append([x for x in chosen])
    else:
        for i in range(0, len(nums)):
            chosen.append(nums[i])
            self.combinationHelper(nums, chosen, target, res)
            chosen.pop()
```

for the input `[2,3,5]` and `target=8` I get the following output:

`[2 2 2 2]`

`[2 3 3]`

`[3 2 3]`

`[3 3 2]`

`[3 5]`

`[5 3]`

The output `[2 3 3]` and `[3 3 2]` and `[3 2 3]` are the same (as `[3,5]` and `[5,3]`).

How can I eliminate these duplicates? The output has to be `list[list[int]]`.

Answer (score 1):

Use a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) and a [`tuple`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences) (you need to use tuple instead of a list because the latter is mutable, and thus cannot be an item of a set):

```
class Solution:
    def combinationSum(self, candidates, target):

      chosen = []
      res = set()
      self.combinationHelper(candidates, chosen, target, res)

      return [list(x) for x in res]

    def combinationHelper(self, nums, chosen, target, res):
        if sum(chosen) > target:
            return
        if sum(chosen) == target:
            res.add(tuple(sorted(chosen)))
        else:
            for i in range(0, len(nums)):
                chosen.append(nums[i])
                self.combinationHelper(nums, chosen, target, res)
                chosen.pop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Add sorted tuples instead of lists. Tuples are *hashables*, such that you can check if they have already been added previously to your `res` list.

Just change

```
if sum(chosen) == target:
    res.append([x for x in chosen])
```

for

```
if sum(chosen) == target:
    v = tuple(sorted(chosen))
    if v not in res: res.append(v)
```

Output:

```
[(2, 2, 2, 2), (2, 3, 3), (3, 5)]
```

Whole code:

```
class Solution:
    def combinationSum(self, candidates, target):

        chosen = []
        res = []
        self.combinationHelper(candidates, chosen, target, res)

        return res

    def combinationHelper(self, nums, chosen, target, res):
        if sum(chosen) > target:
            return
        if sum(chosen) == target:
            v = tuple(sorted(x for x in chosen))
            if v not in res: res.append(v)
        else:
            for i in range(0, len(nums)):
                chosen.append(nums[i])
                self.combinationHelper(nums, chosen, target, res)
                chosen.pop()
Solution().combinationSum([2,3,5], 8)
```

---

*This solution is preferable for small inputs, such as seems to be yours. If using big arrays, please specify and we can change the data structures ;)*

Comment: `(x for x in chosen)` is a redundancy here :)

Comment: @RafaelC thats a great code and it works. Can you also modify this code for larger inputs ?